# How to plot a list of price ranges with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a table with a list of price ranges and the number of occurences:

```
|----------|-----------|-----------|
| Min Price| Max Price | N.Searches|
|----------|-----------|-----------|
|     0    |    10     |    5      |
|----------|-----------|-----------|
|     0    |    20     |    50     |
|----------|-----------|-----------|
|     25   |    50     |    40     |
|----------|-----------|-----------|
|     50   |   100     |    20     |
|----------|-----------|-----------|
```

From my point of view, one possible visualisation, in order to get a rough idea of what are the most searched price, is to multiply every rows by the number of prices within the min and max range and assign a number of searched equal to "Number of Searches"/(Max Price - Min Price).
Then plot an histogram.

Is it correct or there is some other way to summarise this kind of data with ggplot2

Comment: If your point is that there are more searched over a wide price range than narrow, then sure, but I don't know that that would help with telling a story. Are you just playing with data, or is there a back-story to why you're looking at this data?

Comment: Data in the table are related to a product category (eg: Paper Cup). I would like to understand what is the best price range for this product category. The idea is to plot a visualisation that help me to understand what's the distribution of the users searches related to prices.

Comment: I'd think that the *width* of the price range would correlate well with max price, to be honest, in which case you will have issues with your analysis, so your `n / range(price)` is going to be heterogeneous, something I think you should likely be avoiding here. I don't have a suggestion off the top of my head, perhaps somebody else does.

Comment: I've just finish the algorithm. One major change to what I've proposed is that I've to define steps when calculating the price rage. So I used something like `seq(MinPrice, MaxPrice, by=5)` then `n / length(seq(MinPrice, MaxPrice, by=5))` this helps a lot in order to increase the consistency. I also wondering if round prices by the incremental step of seq could lead a better results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just proposing my own solution:
The key here is this mutate statement:

```
mutate(singlePrice = map2(Max.Price, Max.Price, ~ {
    x1 <- .x
    x2 <- .y
    seq(x1, x2, by=1000)})
  ) %>%
```

Then in order to keep the total number of searches consistent:

```
mutate( normSearched = ifelse( priceMax-priceMin == 0,search,search/(length(singlePrice)) ) ) %>%
```

And finally

```
unnest %>%
```

in order to generate the all the row.

After some grouping and summarise steps here are the generated plot with some samples data:
[image]